# struts setup sample application on eclipse

Tags: struts, sample

I am new to strut/web programming and I thought I could learn a lot by reading a sample app. On google, I searched and found a sample app at
http://www.roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2tutorial.zip , the tutorial is really nice and it gives a sample login page.

However, I couldn't run this sample app. I tried posting on the roseindia.net site and got no help neither.

There is no error logged during the start of the server, but when I try and open one of the helloworld's link the following is outputted

I am getting this error

> SEVERE: Could not find action or result There is no Action mapped for
>   action name HelloWorld. - [unknown location]

The folder structure of this thing on my eclipse is

```
/WebContent/WEB-INF/java/net/roseindia/Struts2HelloWorld.java
/WebContent/pages/HelloWorld.jsp
/WebContent/WEB-INF/struts.xml
```

while in strut.xml the sample had..

```
    <action name="HelloWorld" class="net.roseindia.Struts2HelloWorld">
        <result>/pages/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

I am suspecting something in the strut.xml is wrong? I am using eclipse J2EE and tomcat6, I have already tried posting on roseindia's site and got no help.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a fix?

Answer (score 3):

You will learn a lot by reading sample apps.  If your sample doesn't work, perhaps your sample is wrong.

Perhaps you need the actual authoritative documentation.  See [How to setup a basic struts project using Eclipse](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.4/faqs/eclipse.html).  This is the as official as any Eclipse - Struts documentation can be.

Perhaps you need a better example.  See the Struts Community [Projects and Examples](http://struts.sourceforge.net/community/examples.html) web site for numerous examples.

Answer (score 0):

Did you name the file "strut.xml" or "struts.xml"?  It should be the latter (although you could override it if you wanted).  Also, in Struts 2 the struts.xml file has to be in the classpath, not at the root of WEB-INF.  So, in your project, you should put in the "src" folder, so when it deploys it goes into WEB-INF/classes.  You can verify it goes into the correct place by doing an "Export" of the web application to a WAR file and verifying it went into WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score 0):

I've just downloaded a copy of this tutorial, and deployed it to Tomcat 6 - and it works!

Perhaps they have fixed the bug since you last tried? Or perhaps there's something wrong with the way you have Eclipse configured.

Al I did was to unzip the tutorial; copy the directory into the Tomcat webapps directory; start Tomcat; navigate to the Tomcat manager page on my PC; and click the link to the struts2tutorial application.

Give it another try...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Eclipse and solved it by changing the output folder of the source folder to:

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/classes
```